# Transaction TimeOut when we are using JPA Paging Item reader in Spring batch

Tags: jpa, datasource, spring-batch, jta, spring-transactions

**Can anyone help as I am stuck here...Please find the logs below:**

```
2016-04-18 18:13:57,645  WARN [[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] o.h.e.t.s.i.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorTrackingImpl [JDKLogger.java:64]
                HHH000451: Transaction afterCompletion called by a background thread; delaying afterCompletion processing until the original thread can handle it. [status=4]
2016-04-18 18:13:57,646 CASTXN-735623935340919 WARN [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper [JDKLogger.java:44]
                SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2016-04-18 18:13:57,647 CASTXN-735623935340919 ERROR [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper [JDKLogger.java:44]
                Unexpected exception while enlisting XAConnection java.sql.SQLException: Transaction rolled back: Transaction timed out after 30 seconds 
BEA1-018B7B77BA5E55AFE704
    at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.enlist(DataSource.java:1760)
    at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.refreshXAConnAndEnlist(DataSource.java:1645)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTAConnection.getXAConn(JTAConnection.java:232)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTAConnection.checkConnection(JTAConnection.java:94)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTAConnection.checkConnection(JTAConnection.java:77)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Statement.checkStatement(Statement.java:323)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Statement.preInvocationHandler(Statement.java:123)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.setLong(PreparedStatement.java:543)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor271.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$StatementInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:144)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:285)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy238.setLong(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.bindPositionalParameters(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:378)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.bindParameterValues(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:693)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1897)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:558)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:554)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:294)
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.getElementsIterator(CollectionType.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.getElementsIterator(CollectionType.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions.getAllElementsIterator(CascadingActions.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions.access$100(CascadingActions.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$1.getCascadableChildrenIterator(CascadingActions.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:377)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.cascadeBeforeDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:353)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.deleteEntity(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireDelete(SessionImpl.java:929)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.delete(SessionImpl.java:906)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$1.cascade(CascadingActions.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.cascadeBeforeDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:353)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.deleteEntity(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireDelete(SessionImpl.java:929)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.delete(SessionImpl.java:906)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$1.cascade(CascadingActions.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.cascadeAfterDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:376)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.deleteEntity(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireDelete(SessionImpl.java:920)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.delete(SessionImpl.java:896)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.remove(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor291.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:334)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy235.remove(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor291.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:257)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy235.remove(Unknown Source)
    at com.nucleus.persistence.EntityDaoImpl.delete(EntityDaoImpl.java:119)
    at com.nucleus.collection.framework.processes.listener.DeleteFromTempListener.beforeStep(DeleteFromTempListener.java:35)
    at com.nucleus.collection.framework.processes.listener.DeleteFromTempListener$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4989e90e.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:711)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    at com.nucleus.collection.framework.processes.listener.DeleteFromTempListener$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$752407ee.beforeStep(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy270.beforeStep(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.listener.CompositeStepExecutionListener.beforeStep(CompositeStepExecutionListener.java:76)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:191)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:293)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
Caused by: weblogic.transaction.TimedOutException: Transaction timed out after 30 seconds 
BEA1-018B7B77BA5E55AFE704
    at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.enlist(DataSource.java:1758)
    ... 118 more

2016-04-18 18:13:57,741 CASTXN-735623935340919 ERROR [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] o.s.b.c.s.AbstractStep [AbstractStep.java:222]
                Encountered an error executing the step
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Transaction was rolled back in a different thread!
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.remove(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1221) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor291.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) ~[na:2.6 (04-10-2015)]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:334) ~[spring-orm-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy235.remove(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor291.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) ~[na:2.6 (04-10-2015)]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:257) ~[spring-orm-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy235.remove(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at com.nucleus.persistence.EntityDaoImpl.delete(EntityDaoImpl.java:119) ~[neutrino-core-framework-1.2.1-GA.jar:na]
    at com.nucleus.collection.framework.processes.listener.DeleteFromTempListener.beforeStep(DeleteFromTempListener.java:35) ~[collection-framework-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.nucleus.collection.framework.processes.listener.DeleteFromTempListener$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4989e90e.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:711) ~[spring-aop-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262) ~[spring-tx-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-tx-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644) ~[spring-aop-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at com.nucleus.collection.framework.processes.listener.DeleteFromTempListener$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$752407ee.beforeStep(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) ~[na:2.6 (04-10-2015)]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133) ~[spring-aop-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121) ~[spring-aop-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy270.beforeStep(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.listener.CompositeStepExecutionListener.beforeStep(CompositeStepExecutionListener.java:76) ~[spring-batch-core-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:191) ~[spring-batch-core-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135) [spring-batch-core-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61) [spring-batch-core-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60) [spring-batch-core-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144) [spring-batch-core-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124) [spring-batch-core-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135) [spring-batch-core-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:293) [spring-batch-core-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120) [spring-batch-core-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785) [na:1.8.0]
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Transaction was rolled back in a different thread!
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorTrackingImpl.processAnyDelayedAfterCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorTrackingImpl.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.delayedAfterCompletion(SessionImpl.java:664) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionSynchStatus(SessionImpl.java:2157) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getPersistenceContext(SessionImpl.java:1995) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.cascadeBeforeDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:360) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.deleteEntity(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:160) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireDelete(SessionImpl.java:929) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.delete(SessionImpl.java:906) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$1.cascade(CascadingActions.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:379) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:319) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:296) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.cascadeBeforeDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:353) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.deleteEntity(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:160) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireDelete(SessionImpl.java:929) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.delete(SessionImpl.java:906) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$1.cascade(CascadingActions.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.cascadeAfterDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:376) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.deleteEntity(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:312) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:160) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireDelete(SessionImpl.java:920) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.delete(SessionImpl.java:896) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.remove(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
```

Comment: When we have added try catch then we are getting the below error:  javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet

Answer (score 0):

with batch processing it is not uncommon to stumble upon the application server default transaction timeout, did you check the configuration?

for bea weblogic i found [30 seconds](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26180_01/Platform.94/ATGInstallGuide/html/s0407settingthetransactiontimeoutonwe01.html)

> WebLogic will automatically roll back transactions that don’t complete
>   in a certain number of seconds. The default setting is 30 seconds...

Comment: Hi Michael, I have already check the same by updating the JTA timeout to 600 sec on weblogic but that did not work as well. Here i have doubt that why transaction is taking so long?

Comment: When I have added try catch then we are getting the below error: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet

Comment: a transaction spans over a complete chunk in spring batch, e.g. commit-interval = 1000 = 1000 items processed in ONE transaction